# How do I specify to use view from shared project in MvvmCross 6.0

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I am new to both Android and iOS and just got started to learn Xamarin.Forms. (I was a WPF/Silverlight developer)

I spent few days Xamarin.Forms and it was so far so good.
Then I decided I want to learn MvvmCross for IoC and Navigation Service.

However I have been struggle on setting up MvvmCross in my project for few days. I have been reading the tutorial in [Mvvmcross offical site](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/getting-started/mvvmcross-overview) and tries the mimic samples from their [github here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples).

However, I found out all their example is using native view UI from the android project.
But what I wanted is using the same xaml view that defined in the shared project for both Android and iOS.

I couldn't find out

1. How can I specify to use the View from Shared Project?

Answer (score 2):

First things first. You shouldn't be using Shared projects, they're evil (cause of the [preprocessor directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if) and a code mess they can cause). Use .NETStandard option (new PCL's).

Secondly, have a look at the [step by step blog post](https://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2018/04/13/MVX=0F-A-first-MvvmCross-Application-(MVX1-days-of-MvvmCross).aspx) on setting up new Xamarin.Forms project with MvvCross v6, by one of the contributors. He's got a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/nickrandolph/MvxPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/tree/master/Mvx-00-FirstDemo), with Xamarin and Xamarin.Forms samples you could run and play around with

There's also a [Playground project in the MvvmCross sources](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/develop/Projects/Playground), which is being used by contributors to test stuff out. Everything with `.Forms` affix in the name of the project is a Xamarin.Forms project. You could have a look at that, to get a clue on how things should be structured